# Omnigraffle templates: Avoid scaling of some parts of grouped shapes

Tags: templates, scaling, wireframe, mockups

I would like to create my own templates to mockup my web applications. Now imagine I had a Panel shape. It consist of a title and a body devided by a line. When I scale the template in its height later on I would not like to see the title bar scaled.

First of all, is that possible? And if so, how?

My panel should look something like that:

```
-------------------
| Title           |  -> should not change its height on scaling
-------------------
| Some Text in    |
| here..          |
|                 |
|                 |
|    |            |
|    ˇ            |
| Only the body   |
| should scale... |
|                 |
-------------------
```

I am using Omnigraffle 5.4.